# JQuery serializeArray does not include selects without selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the `serializeArray()` method to get the HTML form as JS object. When the form has a select control with "multiple" options but no option is selected the object is not serialized.

Here is an example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/tfzxmr9d/1/

It works fin when it has one or more values. It should return an object with the control name and empty or null value. Is it working as expected ?

Comment: I fixed it inside the function that calls the serializerArray() with this code: `$(this).find("select[multiple]").map(function(){ if(this.value == "") o[this.name]=null});`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot about `$(function(){});` ready syntax. Your code may looks like that. Because jQuery in your case maybe not ready.

```
$(function(){

   function showValues() {
    var fields = $( ":input" ).serializeArray();
    $( "#results" ).empty();
    jQuery.each( fields, function( i, field ) {
      $( "#results" ).append( field.name + ": " + field.value + "<br>" );
    });
  }

  $( ":checkbox, :radio" ).click( showValues );
  $( "select" ).change( showValues );
  showValues();
});
```

Comment: Hi Egor, I got the same results with your code. I guess the problem is inside the serializeArray().

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected with no valid results. To change this behavior add this line right after fields is initialized:

```
fields = fields || [{name: 'multiple', value: 'Null'}];
```

Comment: `serializeArray` always returns an array, so you'd have to actually check for objects with `name: 'multiple'`

Comment: I use a custom function that uses serializeArray() to serialize all HTML forms on my app. I can't use your suggestion because I should add custom code on each form.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!fields.some(function(element){return element.name === "multiple"})){
    fields.push({name: 'multiple', value: 'Null'});
}
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/tfzxmr9d/2/ I can't think of a way around checking the whole array for a 'multiple' so there you go.

But you should probably modify your server-side code to accept the default output since that's the normal way HTML forms are serialized.